# Como listar vários itens na horizontal com título e descrição?

Tags: android, android-studio

eu estou desenvolvendo uma loja virtual para Android e gostaria de listar os produtos na horizontal com o seu titulo, preço e descrição,  tentei fazer usando o LinearLayout mas acabou dando erro devido a quantidade que eu usei, agradeceria muito se pudessem me dar alguma dica ou conteúdo sobre o assunto.

como aparece na imagem abaixo:
[image: Exemplo]

Comment: Você poderia tentar implementar um ScrollView à sua activity

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Não é bem isso, o que eu estou tentado fazer é listar os listar os itens na horizontal sem necessidade de rolagem

Comment: Mas se for muitos itens pode nn caber na tela de todos os aparelhos

Comment: Você usa recyclerview?

Comment: Sim vou usar um ScrollView pra isso, Mas quando a organização dos itens(titulo, preço e descrição) não consigo listar horizontalmente esses itens

Comment: Não, nunca usei.

Comment: Então você deve usar.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada o assunto

Comment: use um recycleview na horizontal.

Scrollview é dificil de fazer um tem baixa performace